# Confusion about Pandas DataFrame.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I write the code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,4).reshape((2,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
print("dataframe: \n", df2)
print("mean: \n", df2.mean(0))
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x - [1, 2], axis=0)
print("altered df2: \n", df2)
```

It gives me the results:

```
dataframe: 
    A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
mean: 
 A    1.5
B    1.5
dtype: float64
altered df2: 
    A  B
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

So first, I've asked it to give me the mean along `axis=0`. In my mind, this means count each row as a vector and find the average of those vectors. It seems that Pandas agrees with me on this one!

However, I then use the `DataFrame.apply()` function, and I again specify `axis=0`. Here I expect the same logic to work, which is for an operation on each row to be executed. In this case `lambda x: x - [1, 2]`. The result I expect is :

```
    A  B
0  0  -1
1  1  0
```

But instead, when I specify axis=0 (rows), it actually does the operation on the columns.

I'm having a very hard time with pandas, specifically wrapping my head around how it indexes rows and columns, and this has further added to the confusion. As it stands, every time I think I get how things work, I find out I'm wrong, so nothing ever sticks in my brain. **I'm asking for an easy way to think about this stuff so that it sticks in my dyslexic little head.**

Comment: `axis = 0` apply a function in each column, `axis=0` get mean in each column

Comment: @ansev, Thank you, yes I stated that this is occurring in my question. What I want to know is why, when in every other context axis=0 specifically refers to rows. For example, applying df.mean(0) returns a row. I do see that each element in the row is an average of the columns. So perhaps I should just switch my thinking: 0 equals columns, 1 equals rows.